# How to get message error from Exception whit Ajax MVC 5 core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to fill Field with user information using ajax.
It work well;

**ACTION**

```
  public Operatore User(int Id)
        {
            Operatore User = new Operatore();

            /*
             DO STUFF TO FILL USER

             */

            /*if something go wrong 
              throw new Exception("user does not exist");
             */


            return User;
        }
```

but if i throw Exception with custom message i can't read it in Ajax

**AJAX**

```
     $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "@Url.Action("User")",
                        data: { Id: $("#ID").find(":selected").val()},
                        success: function (msg) {
                        /*FILL THE DATA*/
                        /*It works well*/
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert(error.Message);
                           /*this does not work*/
                        }
                    });
```

I just need to read my custom error message.
The alert return "undefined"
How can i do?

Comment: What does [*this does not work*](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) mean?

Comment: Don't use `alert` for debugging, debug properly, or at a minimum, use `console.log` as it will output objects - `console.log(error)` then look at what's being displayed to see if your message is in there under a different property.

Comment: Note that you can usually configure whether *or not* error messages are passed to the front end in the web.config.  If they're blocked at that level, you won't be able to get them in your js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something goes wrong (in operatore):

```
Response.StatusCode = 500;
Return Json("Error Message");
```

StatusCode is necessary to mislead Ajax.
Beware your action must return an object.

In Ajax:

```
 error: function (error) {
        alert(error.responseJSON);
 }
```